# How to remove unexpected accessibility event on Android home screen?

Tags: android, events, accessibility, screen

I woke up this morning to this on my phone I did nothing that I'm aware of to cause this.

Restarted my phone and attempted to clear cache partition but it wasn't an option my list.
This is what I have on the home screen:

AccessibilityEvent
TYPE WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED
ContentChangeTypes=CONTENT_CH
ANGE TYPE SUBTREE time=49634 class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.android.systemui" enabled ScrollX-0 ScrollY=0 MaxScrollX=0
MaxScrollY=0
How do I get this off my phone?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add a screenshot? To be honest those events fire a lot on devices all the time, regardless of whether an accessibility service is on or not. You could try:
`adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services \"\"` but if it does nothing, then it's not an accessibility thing